# Why does tkinter sometimes work without mainloop in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Here's code for a little game.  You're supposed to hit buttons that say 'click' to score points and avoid hitting buttons that say 'clack' or 'cluck' which cause you to lose points.  The first weird thing is that the program works fine under IDLE even though it doesn't include a call to mainloop.  The second is that it stops working if we add the following line at the bottom:

```
input('Hit enter to continue')
```

No game window appears, even after we hit enter.  Adding a different line at the end like

```
print('hello')
```

does not have this effect.

Can anyone explain to me what's going on?  I know that GUI programs used to run under IDLE's own mainloop, but that was a long time ago in Python 2 and definitely wasn't generally true under Python 3, at least last time I checked.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

score = 0

root = Tk()

scoreFrame = Frame(root)
scoreFrame.pack(expand = YES, fill = BOTH)

scoreLabel = Label(scoreFrame)
scoreLabel.pack()

def showScore():
    scoreLabel['text'] = 'Score: {0}'.format(score)
    scoreLabel.pack()

clickFrame = Frame(root)
clickFrame.pack(side = BOTTOM, expand = YES, fill = BOTH)

def changeLabels():
    for button in buttons:
        button['text'] = random.choice(['click', 'clack', 'cluck'])
        button['bg'] = buttonDefaultColor
    root.after(1500, changeLabels)

def makeButton():
    button = Button(clickFrame)
    def cmd():
        global score
        if button['bg'] == buttonDefaultColor:
            if button['text'] == 'click':
                score += 10
                button['bg'] = 'light green'
        else:
            score -= 10
            button['bg'] = 'light yellow'

    button['command'] = cmd
    button.pack(side = LEFT, expand = YES, fill = BOTH)
    return button

buttons = [makeButton() for i in range(5)]
buttonDefaultColor = buttons[0]['bg']
changeLabels() 
showScore()
```

Added: The first three comments all suggest that IDLE is running the event loop for me, making mainloop unnecessary but (1) I remember clearly when this suddenly stopped being true some years back (not that IDLE stopped running mainloop, but that GUI programs running under it did not need to run mainloop themselves) and (2) no one has explained why the input statement at the end breaks the program.

Comment: IDLE uses the interactive interpreter, so things like drawing the GUI don't require mainloop.

Comment: `tkinter` was used to create `IDLE`, [turtle](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/turtle.html), Zelle [graphics.py](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/), [easygui](http://easygui.sourceforge.net/), etc. `IDLE` runs `mainloop` to work - but other modules use this `mainloop` automatically to run own elements.

Comment: It's always been true that tkinter needs an event loop. Either the tools you're using to launch the program has one, or your program needs one. That has never changed.